# Remove the item from ComboBox 2 that was selected from ComboBox 1

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have two comboBoxes take the data from the same List witch contains an objects.
How to remove the selected item in ComboBox 1 from items in ComboBox 2?

```
comboBox1.DataSource = CityList;    //CityList is list contain objects
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";

comboBox2.DataSource = CityList;
comboBox2.ValueMember = "ID";
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBoxTargetState.Items.Remove(comboBoxCurrentState.SelectedItem); // give me an excption
```

Comment: it looks like that you have 4 comboboxes: `comboBox1`,`comboBox2`,`comboBoxTargetState` and `comboBoxCurrentState`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `DataSource`, you have to remove the item from source instead from `Items` (because it's readonly when the ComboBox is data bound):

```
if(comboBoxCurrentState.SelectedIndex > -1)
  CityList.RemoveAt(comboBoxCurrentState.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: Understood, but i want to remove the selected item in ComboBox1 from ComboBox2???

Comment: @AnasSalem your comboBoxes have the same DataSource, if so you have to prepare 2 different DataSource for your comboBox.